# What is the semantic contribution of 献 to 文献?

Tags: meaning, kanji

Whenever I see 献, I am reminded of 貢献、献金、献立, which implies a meaning of "offering." I checked 文献 and it was defined as "literature, documents." It seems to me that among the 熟語 with 献, this is the odd one out.

Can anyone shed light on the semantic contribution of 献 to 文献? Thank you.

Comment: Definitions will sometimes contain the explanations of the etymology directly within them. https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%96%87%E7%8C%AE

Comment: 「献」は賢の意。文字として伝えられているものと賢人が記憶しているもの、の意

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try reading parenthetical notes from now on haha

Comment: Maybe you can ask it in Chinese SE for a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand it's derived from 論語

> [子曰：“夏礼，吾能言之，杞不足徵也；殷礼，吾能言之，宋不足徵也。文献不足故也，足则吾能徵之矣。”](https://ctext.org/analects/ba-yi/ens?searchu=%E6%96%87%E7%8D%BB%E4%B8%8D%E8%B6%B3%E6%95%85%E4%B9%9F%EF%BC%8C%E8%B6%B3%E5%89%87%E5%90%BE%E8%83%BD%E5%BE%B5%E4%B9%8B%E7%9F%A3%E3%80%82)

And it originally meant "written records and wise men" (as opposed to just written records), but the phrase is now used exclusively to refer to written records.